# Which set does $\infty$ refer to?

Tags: infinity

The extended real number line is sometimes written as $\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\} \cup \{-\infty\}$.

In ZFC, this would imply that $+\infty$ is some set. In other words, the string $+\infty$ is an identifier for a particular set.

So... which set is this? Or this this technically an abuse of notation?

Comment: it doesn't refer to any particular set, just any set that isn't already an element of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For the purpose of compactification you may use any object that is not a real number, take $+\infty=\{\mathbb R_+\}$ for example.

Comment: @user363464 since you got here first, I think you should get to expand your comment into an answer so that the question is no longer unanswered.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Since you got here second and the other user hasn't, I think you should expand your comment into an answer so that the question is no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of compactification you may use any object that is not a real number, take $+\infty=\{\mathbb R_+\}$ for example.